# Sourcetree: How to see all modified/added/deleted files in a range of commits?

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

Example:
I have a project with 100 commits

I want to see graphically everything that happened between commit 91 and commit 93 in terms of deleted, added, modified files, all togheter.

*What it does now is that it only shows the changes of the last commit I click, even if I pick a range of commits. Ex: If I click 90 then Shift+Click commit 93 it shows me only the changes of the commit nr. 93.*

If in commit 91 I deleted 5 files from project, in commit 92 I modified 3 files and in commit 93 I added 8 files I want to press Shift+Click on commit 91 and 93 and see all these changes listed togheter.

I've seen a few ways to do it from console, which I hate. Is possible through the GUI?

Here's what I mean:

[image: commits]

Comment: Isn't that exactly what it does? Or at least if you also select commit 90.

Comment: @CodeCaster Unfortunately not, It only show the last one you click. Added that to the question as I've realized it was unclear and needs to be specified.